# Vuetify with Webpack 4 and Polyfill getting SCRIPT1003

Tags: vue.js, internet-explorer, babeljs, vuetify.js

Error:

```
SCRIPT1003: Expected ':'
```

Works in Chrome but not with IE 11. Using: Vue 2.6.10 / Vuetify 2.0.8 / Webpack 4.39.2. I've tried both babel-polyfill and @babel/polyfill but the results are the same. I'm not using Vue-CLI. I can't seem to find out how to force transpilation of Vuetify (without Vue-CLI).

.babelrc

```
{
"presets" :
[
    [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        {
            "modules"  : false,
            "targets"  :
            {
                "browsers":
                [
                    "> 1%",
                    "last 2 versions",
                    "not ie <= 8",
                    "ie >= 11"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
],
"plugins" :
[
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-shorthand-properties"
]
```

}

index.js

```
import '@babel/polyfill';

import Vue      from 'vue';
import Vuex     from 'vuex';
import App      from '@/App';
import Store    from '@/store';
import vuetify  from '@/plugins/vuetify';


// Global event hub/bus.
Vue.prototype.$eventHub = new Vue();

// Main Vue instance.
new Vue
({
    // The Element that VUE is bound to in the main component.
    el: '#app',

    // Initialize the store.
    store : Store,

    vuetify : vuetify,

    // Renders the Layout component.
    render : h => h( App )
});
```

webpack.config

```
entry :
{
    polyfill : '@babel/polyfill',
    main     : helpers.root( 'src', 'index' ),
},
```

Comment: This problem is limited to Vuetify a-la-cart setup. Full install works on IE.

Comment: Did you try to click on that error to check on which line this error is occurred ? Try to post that line of code may help to find the issue. Ref: https://qiita.com/gasekao/items/09158675f83183dd43da and https://forum.vuejs.org/t/ie11-vue-cli-webpack-babel-script1003-error/16257/8